# HoloEverywhere: Dark action bars and dialogs

Tags: android, dialog, styles, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using HoloEverywhere library, I need action bars and dialogs (ProgressDialog and AlertDialog) to be styled with the Holo Dark theme and the rest of the controls with the Holo Light.

I set the application theme to Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar (this is the closest to what I need so far) but with this I get Light dialogs.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create new context wrapper for dialogs:

```
Context dialogContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Holo_Theme);
Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(dialogContext).create();
```